# Pandas API on Spark - Difference between two date columns

Tags: python, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I want the difference between two date columns in the number of days. 
In pandas dataframe difference in two "datetime64" type columns returns number of days 
but in pyspark.pandas dataframe the difference is returned in the "int" type.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps

data = {
    "d1": [
        "2019-05-18",
        "2019-06-21",
        "2019-05-08",
        "2019-05-22",
        "2019-11-20",
        "2019-05-29",
    ],
    "d2": [
        "2019-05-21",
        "2019-06-21",
        "2019-05-09",
        "2019-05-23",
        "2019-11-21",
        "2019-05-30",
    ],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[["d1", "d2"]] = df[["d1", "d2"]].astype("datetime64")
pdf = ps.from_pandas(df)

df["diff"] = (df["d1"] - df["d2"]).dt.days
pdf["diff"] = pdf["d1"] - pdf["d2"]
```

Pandas difference Output: [-3, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1] 
PySpark difference Output: [-259200,       0,  -86400,  -86400,  -86400,  -86400]

Expected Op: PySpark difference should return in days format and be accessible using dt.days

Tried:

1. Converting int column to DateTime

```
pdf['diff'].astype('datetime64')

>>>['1969-12-29 00:00:00', '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
    '1969-12-31 00:00:00', '1969-12-31 00:00:00',
    '1969-12-31 00:00:00', '1969-12-31 00:00:00']
```

2. The current sol that I am working with is

```
temp = pdf[["d1", "d2"]].to_pandas()
pdf["diff2"] = ps.Series((temp["d1"] - temp["d2"]).dt.days)

>>> [-3,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

This sol works, but for large datasets converting to pandas and doing operation on the two columns adds overhead and increases the runtime. So any concise way to get difference in two datetime columns in pyspark.pandas dataframe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the diff is a timestamp diff, therefore, the result is in second : `259200 / 3600 / 24 = 3`. Just add some math and you'll get your expected result.

In pure Spark, you can also use [`datediff`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.datediff) :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 


df.select(F.datediff(df.d2, df.d1).alias('diff')).collect()
# [Row(diff=32)]
```

Comment: the division thing helps, but data_diff errored out "'DataFrame' object has no attribute select'"

Comment: have you tried simply `pdf["diff"] = (pdf["d1"] - pdf["d2"]).dt.days`?

Comment: yup, that was the first thing I tried, but the pyspark.dataframe return and "int" right so dt.days doesn't work

Comment: but this ways also works : **pdf["diff"] = pdf[['d1','d2']].apply(lambda x:(x[0]-x[1]).days, axis=1)**

Answer (score 1):

Apply [to_timedelta()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and use unit as "seconds":

```py
pdf["diff"] = (pdf['d1'] - pdf['d2']).apply(lambda x: ps.to_timedelta(x, unit="seconds").days)
```

Full example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps

data = {
    'd1':['2019-05-18','2019-06-21','2019-05-08','2019-05-22','2019-11-20','2019-05-29'],
    'd2':['2019-05-21','2019-06-21','2019-05-09','2019-05-23','2019-11-21','2019-05-30']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[['d1','d2']] = df[['d1','d2']].astype('datetime64')
pdf = ps.from_pandas(df)

df["diff"] = (df['d1'] - df['d2']).dt.days

pdf["diff"] = (pdf['d1'] - pdf['d2']).apply(lambda x: ps.to_timedelta(x, unit="seconds").days)

print(pdf)

[Out]:
          d1         d2  diff
0 2019-05-18 2019-05-21    -3
1 2019-06-21 2019-06-21     0
2 2019-05-08 2019-05-09    -1
3 2019-05-22 2019-05-23    -1
4 2019-11-20 2019-11-21    -1
5 2019-05-29 2019-05-30    -1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but  to_timedelta errored out for me think because of the spark version, which i can't upgrade due to env constraints